# UICollectionView cell is aligned off the screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am new to using UICollectionView since I've been using UITableView, so I apologize beforehand.

Anyways, I have some simple code but for some reason that I'm not familiar with yet, some of the cells are placed off screen instead of being moved down to the next level.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    array = [ [NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Apple", @"Is", @"The", @"Bomb", @".com", @":D", nil];
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5.0;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return array.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

    label.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
    [cell.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];

    [cell.layer setCornerRadius:10.f];

    return cell;
}
```

[image]

What happened to the cells with "Bomb" and ".com"? Why is it cut off screen?

Comment: What is the frame of your collection view? How did you set that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your view constraints on the Collection View.  Check out Autolayout programming to set up constraints for the UICollectionView.

Comment: How I know how set up the constraints for a UITableView but not a UICollectionView, I do not know. What an idiot! :)